# SQLite - Selecting rows from table using a comparer function

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in my SQLite database where one of the columns is just a free text.
Also, I have a custom function defined that calculates the *Levenshtein distance* of two given strings. Basically is just a comparer function that returns an integer value (distance between both strings).

My goal is to retrieve **ALL the rows** from that table that share a distance lower than a given value D between them.

Is this possible using queries? I thought GROUP BY would be the answer but I haven't gotten any semi decent results I can share.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the table with itself:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable T1 JOIN
     MyTable T2 ON T1.ID < T2.ID AND
                   LDist(T1.TextColumn, T2.TextColumn) < 42
```

(The `ID` comparison prevents returning two result records for the same pair.)

Comment: Thanks CL. but that query assumes I'm comparing each value in the TextColumn against a fixed string "search text". What I need is to compare the TextColumn values among themselves using the Comparer function to get the ones sharing a distance < D

Comment: This is definitely a step forward :) I still have to filter the results because I'm getting the same row multiple times (like row 1 in comparison to row 2 and the other way around) but, at least, I get the wanted rows in the output.